# php array storing from $_FILES

Tags: php, arrays

Hello I have a stupid problem I want to upload a file to a server. The process works but I have multiple file input fields and I want to store their names inside of an array and that doesn't work -_-:

```
  $target_dir = "../steppys/" . $id;
  $target_files = array();
  $target_files[] = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["image1"]["name"]);
  echo $target_files[0];
```

Thats the code and it will echo 0;
BUT when this:

```
$target_dir = "../steppys/" . $id;
echo $target_dir . basename($_FILES["image1"]["name"]);
```

It give me the path name. And I need to add this to an array.
Array are also working fine
I have tested them(also dynamically adding things).

Htmlcode(simple form but also tested):

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="test.php" method="post">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" type="file" name="image1" />
      </div>
      <input class="form-control" type="submit">
    </form>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: you need to treat the file input as an array/multiples and/or add more inputs. It's all in the manual examples

Comment: @Fred-ii- Can you give me an example?

Answer (score 0):

Yes I solved the problem I didn't uploaded one file...